Unable To Install "MyApp" - Has missing or invalid CFBundleExecutable in its Info.plist (OpenCV)
After adding OpenCV to the project, my react native iOS app builds successfully but doesn't install onto any devices. By looking at the error Xcode is giving, it seems like an issue with the CFBundleExecutable key in the Info.plist file of either the OpenCV framework or the app's main Info.plist file:
Unable to Install “MyApp”
Bundle at path /var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.OG4mON/extracted/MyApp.app/Frameworks/opencv2.framework has missing or invalid CFBundleExecutable in its Info.plist

However, when I looked in the framework there is no Info.plist file... also, when I tried to add a Info.plist file with a CFBundleExecutable key,
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>

this didn't do anything. Along with this, I checked MyApp/Info.plist to see if the CFBundleExecutable was set correctly and it was, which leads me to believe this Missing or Invalid CFBundleExecutable error is misleading. Has anyone else experienced this while adding OpenCV or another framework?

I solved this issue by going into Xcode and going to General -> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content. Once there, i changed the OpenCV framework to not be embedded. By switching from Embed & Sign to Do Not Embed this resolved the error and the app runs on physical devices and simulators. Hopefully this helps someone resolve their framework error like this too.

if you solved your issue, post your solution as an answer.

Okay, thank you! @ChristophRackwitz

I solved this issue by going into Xcode and going to General -> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content. Once there, i changed the OpenCV framework to not be embedded. By switching from Embed & Sign to Do Not Embed this resolved the error and the app runs on physical devices and simulators. Hopefully this helps someone resolve their framework error like this too.
